# Install Gnome on Linux Server and Access it via Remote

Tags: gnome

I have a remote linux server. I want to access it remote desktop style from windows.

I found this tutorial
http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server

And a bunch of others

All are so complicated.

Are there easier tutorial? Something that can explain what is Gnome, what is VNC, what is tiger-vnc, etc?

Comment: Which distro is running on the server?

Comment: centosh don't know which version

Comment: “remote desktop style” meaning that there is a used logged in on the console of the server, and you want to see and use the same windows? Or meaning that you want to run applications on the server and have them display on your local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a GUI installed and running and you really want to connect from windows, then [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx) could work (it basically uses Wine, which is basically a Windows emulator, to run, so it's a bit large)

Comment: The server is totally remote. So I do not have GUI running until I can have GUI running from windows.

Comment: Basically I ordered a dedi. I just don't know why gnome is not part of standard instalation.

Comment: @JimThio Do you have a vps? If so, you can just install gnome or some other environment.